# Compute the Smith Normal Form for some characteristic matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $k$ be a field. I'm trying to compute the Smith Normal Form for the characteristic matrix of $A=(a_{ij}) \in M_{n\times n} (k)$ where $a_{ij}=1$ for all $i$ and $j$.

I haven't figured it out yet but when I use Maplesoft to compute $SmithForm(A)$ for finite integer values of $n$, it returns the $n\times n$ matrix with $1$ in position $1,1$ and zero everywhere else. Does anyone know why it's doing this?  expected it to at least return a matrix in which each diagonal entry is nonzero.

Thanks

Comment: does not the smith form conserve the rank? the rank of $A$ is one, so the smith form will have only one nonzero diagonal.

Comment: Smith normal form is essentially doing row reductions and then doing column reductions. For fields this is easy because there are invertible elements. Doing row reductions on $A$ gives the first row of all $1$'s, and $0$'s everywhere else. Then doing column reductions on entries right of the first entry gives all $0$'s.

Comment: Is not the Smith Normal Form, by definition, supposed to have diagonal consisting of $1$'s and monic nonzero elements of $k[x]$?

Comment: [Not really, no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Definition)... where would you get those polynomials from, anyway?

Comment: I understand better now, thank you, everyone... Thanks for pointing out that definition. I've come across a couple sources that hide the fact that the diagonal entries may be zero.

Comment: @Itried Are you sure you don't want the SNF of the *characteristic matrix* of $A$?

Comment: @user26857 Yes, that's exactly what I want. My textbook defines the Smith Normal form of $A$ to be the diagonal matrix obtained by performing ERO on $xI-A$. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the SNF of $XI-A$ I suggest you to switch between the first and the last columns, then subtract the first row from all the others, and so on. You will easily get the SNF: $\operatorname{diag}(1,X,\dots,X,X(X-n))$.